# Finding all possible 4-element arrays with elements made up of products of 3 unique values

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of unique values `x, y, z`, find all possible unique 4-element arrays that can be made up of products of `x, y, z` where each value of `x, y, z` is used once in each array.

For example, in the case of only `x, y` and 2-element arrays, the answer would be:

```
[x*y, 1]
[x, y]
[1, x*y]
[y, x]
```

As a skeleton code (in Python):

```py
def f(x, y, z):
  """returns list of 4-element lists"""
  # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import itertools

def f(x, y, z):
  variants = [(x, y, z, 1), (x*y, z, 1, 1), (x*z, y, 1, 1), (y*z, x, 1, 1), (x*y*z, 1, 1, 1)]
  s = set()
  for variant in variants:
    permutations = itertools.permutations(variant)
    for p in permutations:
      s.add(p)
  return s
```

Answer (score 0):

Every argument can be placed in 4 possible positions, so we have 4^3=64 variants. We can match every combination with integer in range 0..63.

```
def f(x, y, z):
    res = []
    a = (x, y, z) # for simpler indexing
    for i in range(4**3):   #64 combinations
        t = i               #use counter as combination source 
        p = [1]*4       
        for k in range(3):   
            p[t&3] *= a[k]   #considering 2-bit chunks as position in 4-element list p
            t >>= 2
        res.append(p)
    return res

print(f(2,3,5))
```

Universal code for arbitrary argument list and array length

```
def funi(alist, places):
    n = len(alist)
    res = []
    for i in range(places**n):
        t = i
        p = [1]*places
        for k in range(n):
            p[t%places] *= alist[k]
            t //= places
        res.append(p)
    return res
```

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to implement your function..

```
def f(x, y, z):
    # Create a list of all possible combinations of x, y, and z
    combinations = [(a, b, c) for a in (x, y, z) for b in (x, y, z) for c in (x, y, z) if a != b and b != c and a != c]

    # Create a list of all possible products of two elements in the combinations list
    products = [a*b for a, b, c in combinations] + [b*c for a, b, c in combinations] + [a*c for a, b, c in combinations]

    # Create a list of all possible products of three elements in the combinations list
    products += [a*b*c for a, b, c in combinations]

    # Create a list of all possible 4-element arrays that can be made up of products of x, y, z
    arrays = [[a, b, c, d] for a in products for b in products for c in products for d in products if len(set([a, b, c, d])) == 4]

    # Remove any duplicate arrays from the list
    unique_arrays = list(set([tuple(sorted(array)) for array in arrays]))

    # Convert the tuples back to lists and return the final list of unique 4-element arrays
    return [list(array) for array in unique_arrays]
```